# Как посчитать количество вхождений подстроки в массиве?

Tags: php

Всем привет!

Есть задача:
На странице https://****.ru есть какое-то количество ссылок. Анкором ссылки называется текст, находящийся между тегами `<a>` и `</a>`. Посчитайте сколько раз встречается буква "з" внутри анкоров ссылок на этой странице. Регистр буквы не учитывайте, считайте все вхождения этой буквы: как в прописном, так и строчном видах.

Мой код на данный момент:

```
$html = file_get_contents($url); //забираю html с удаленного сайта

 if (preg_match_all('|<a(.+)</a>|isU', $html, $arr)) { // забираю все, что есть между тегами a
   // echo $arr[0][0] . " " . $arr[0][1] . " " . $arr[0][2] . "<br />";
   // echo $arr[1][0] . " " . $arr[1][1] . " " . $arr[1][2];
 }
```

Подскажите, как посчитать количество вхождений подстроки? Возможно как то изменить шаблон для функции `preg_match_all`?

Comment: Ну это же тестовое задание )

Comment: в описание функции preg_match_all заглядывал?

Comment: echo sizeof($arr); //это кол-во найденных строк согласно регулярному выражению